# Customizing add to cart message in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, notice

I added a link to the cart page inside the message that pops up when a product is successfully added to the cart in Woocommerce. This however does nothing when it's clicked. The inspector does show the correct working link.

```
// Add cart page URL
        global $woocommerce;
        $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();

        $returnArray['messages']['success'] = sprintf(__('Products successfully added to cart! <a href="%s">View cart</a>','woocommerce'), $cart_url);
```

I think I should note that this part of the code is used twice in the page:

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
```

I understand that using the same variable twice could cause issues but in this case they should do the same thing anyway but could this be the cause?

EDIT: changed the method for getting the cart page URL

```
$returnArray['messages']['success'] = sprintf( __('Products successfully added to cart! <a href="%s">View cart</a>','sf-european-fasteners'), wc_get_cart_url() );
```